# Install Ubuntu on Macbook Pro 6.2

Tags: macosx

I am trying to install ubunut on mac book pro 6.2 , i found out that there is a specific release of MAC.

64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop image

but it is not working for me , when ever i try to boot from it i got black screen with cursor blinking , directly without getting the image to try or install ubuntu . i tried both 12.10 and 13.04

While when trying the stock

64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image

it works directly and i am able to install ubuntu .

I want to try the mac version to see if my dual vga (intel and nvidia) will work .

Any idea why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

during instalation reduce resolution mode to something like 800*600 and stick with it until you activate the graphics drivers

edit: this will require for you to start all over